# Separate IDP from Database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, next.js, next-auth

I'm trying to setup a configuration where the identity provider authenticates the user, and then the user is either provisioned into the database on the spot if they are not in the database or if they already exist in the database, associated data is returned.

I'm using Firebase as the database.  What is a good way to implement this setup?  I currently have the front-end portion of my app working with authentication from my IDP.  I do not want to use Firebase authentication since I already have an IDP, but want to be able to securely get user data from Firebase once they are signed in.  Thank you in advance.

**Update**:
I ended up going a different direction and using Firebase Auth with Google, but then used the hosted domain (hd) parameter to limit authentication to Google Accounts from a specific organization.  I know this won't serve all purposes, but it worked for my purposes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be able to securely get user data from Firebase once they
> are signed in

If you want to secure the access to your Firebase database (Firestore or the RTDB?) when accessing it **via a client SDK** you need to use the Firestore or the RTDB Security Rules.

If you don't want to authenticate your users through the Firebase Auth Service you can create you own Custom Tokens as explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens).

**Excerpts from the doc:**

> You generate the custom JSON Web Tokens (JWTs) on your server, pass them back to
> a client device, and then use them to authenticate via the
> `signInWithCustomToken()` method.
>
> ...
>
> You can create a custom JWT with the Firebase Admin SDK, or you can
> use a third-party JWT library if your server is written in a language
> which Firebase does not natively support.

Comment: Hello @StevenBash, did you have the time to look at the answer?

Comment: Yes I did, Renaud! Thank you for the help!

Comment: Glad to help you. If my answer solved your problem, please accept it in such a way others SO users know that it solves the question.